# Background banner not showing in divbox

Tags: asp.net, css, image, html

I'm using html and CSS to create a master page for ASP.NET. However my top banner is not working, unlike the rest of the pictures. It does however show on the design tab of Visual studio. I have place the necessary code only below, can someone help please?

HTML:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">        
        <div id="container">
            <div runat="server" id="top">
                        </div>
                </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body 
{
    background-image: url(../Images/background_5.jpg);
    /*font-family: Arial;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgb(225, 201, 201);
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;*/
}

#form1
{
    width: 1200px;
}

#container
{
    background-color: White;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    float:left;
    left: 50%;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: -450px;
    width: 910px;
    height: 1800px;
}

#top
{
    background: url(../Images/Banner.jpg);
    /*padding-left: 10px;*/
    height: 250px;
    width: 900px;   
}

#loginDiv
{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    height: 142px;
    font-family:Century Gothic;
}

#middle
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 900px;
}
```

If you would like to see the entire HTML code, it's attached below:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">        
        <div id="container">
            <div runat="server" id="top">

                <asp:Label ID="WelcomeLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Italic="False" 
                    Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Overline="False" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Sign out" BackColor="Black" 
                    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Outset" Font-Names="Century Gothic" 
                    ForeColor="White" Width="75px" />

                <br />

               <div id="loginDiv" runat="server">
                     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                     <br />
                     <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Login" 
                         BackColor="Black" BorderStyle="Outset" Font-Names="Century Gothic" 
                         ForeColor="White"/>
                     <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
            </div> 

            <div runat="server" id="middle">
                <div id="left" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 33%; margin: 0; ">
                    Categories
                    <ul>
                        <li>option 1</li>
                        <li>option 2</li>
                        <li>option 3</li>
                        <li>option 4</li>
                    </ul>

                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblItemsShoppingCart" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Right" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 67%; margin: 0; " class="sf_colsOut">                 
                        <asp:contentplaceholder id="contentplace" runat="server" />                 
                </div>
            </div> 
            </div> 

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried with `background-image` instead of `background` ?

Comment: If you can create a fiddle link and replicate the problem there, I think you'll get the answer

Answer (score 0):

does it actually look like this in your code?: `background: url(../Images/Banner.jpg);`

The `../` isn't the proper way to write a path, take that bit off and you should be golden, like so:

`(images/banner.jpg);`

edit: I also recommend putting the banner in a `<div>`, giving it an ID and using `position: fixed; top: 0px;` to attach it to the top of the page.  Remember to give it a width and height as well or it won't display.

Comment: `../` you really know how this works?? how to avoid it if you need a step back on the path?

Comment: yes but if that image is just in the images folder why would there be a need to step backward in the path?  If it's written like that and it's in the images folder it will not display.

Comment: The other images display with that path. So I doubt that that's the issue. I did not set it in a new div because I have textboxes and buttons on the banner, so it has to be a background image.

Comment: is it possible to relocate the file? if going backwards through directories all the way to the root still isn't retrieving the file properly it could be the browser is doing something quirky?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this path "~/Images/Banner.jpg" . To me sometimes some paths do not work, others are not. sometimes solve so.

Answer (score 0):

Link to css file:

```
 <link href="~/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also, to the images